# How to get real FPS with createjs

Tags: android, mobile, easeljs, createjs

I created a game with createjs, but it runs very slowly on a mobile.

I added a function to show FPS obtained with `createjs.Ticker.getMeasuredFPS()`. However, the FPS shown by the function is quite normal. I set the FPS to 60, and the result of `getMeasuredFPS()` is about 55-60, while the animation is laggy and the FPS shouldn't be so high (it might be 5-10).

How can I get the real FPS on the device?

How can I profile it on a mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getMeasuredFPS()` is well tested, and should be accurate. That said, there's always a chance your mobile browser is doing something tricky (running the code every tick, but not rendering). There's also a chance your code may not be updating properly.

Either way, it's worth looking at a couple of alternatives. You can check `getMeasuredTickTime()`, which will tell you the average time spent in each tick (see the docs for more info).

You should also take a look at profiling using devtools.
http://google.com?q=profile+mobile+chrome

Comment: The browser I tested is the one come with the phone, I think it may be customized. However, after I set the timingMode to `RAF_SYNCHED`, the FPS becomes more reasonable, although I don't know why. Thank you for your advice!